# Clutch gear test

Tags: technic, building, gears

I have two white 24t [clutch gears](http://sariel.pl/2009/09/gears-tutorial/), one marked as 2.5-5Ncm and another unmarked - how can I assembled them in a way to test which one "gives" first ) i.e. has torque before it slips - I was thinking to lock the axle on both and then driving them through a differential, but I am not sure how "fair" or symmetric a lego differential would be for driving them, and also noticed that they don't have a constant torque, but rather a shifting amount depending on the position, so some way to determine both the peak and average torque of them would be ideal, but I am not sure of as to design such as test, thus this question:

How can I test two clutch gears to determine their differences?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example. Just replace both black gears with the clutch gears you want to test. Hold 1 clutch while turning the main black axle. Then hold the the other clutch while turning the mail black axle. In one of them you will feel more friction while turning the axle. This clutch you are holding then is tighter/ offers more friction.
[image]